# How To integrate flowplayer in ext.net2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flowplayer, ext.net

I try to integrate Flow Player in Ext.net.
How to Set Video src in code (.cs file).

```
<ext:Panel ID="VideoPanel" runat="server" Split="true">
<Content>
          <div class="flowplayer">
               <video src="../video/Ganesh.mp4"></video>
          </div>
 </Content>
 </ext:Panel>
```

can i add video source by code (.cs file)

I am using video in My Broadcast Page.
It's use in Form Panel

My ASPX Code is:-----

```
<ext:FormPanel 
                    ID="FormPanel1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Region="East" Title="Broadcasting Details"
                    Split="true"
                    Margins="0 5 5 5"
                    Frame="true" ColumnWidth="0.3" 
                    Width="280"
                    DefaultAnchor="100%">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:TextField ID="TextTitle" runat="server" FieldLabel="Title" Name="title" />
                        <ext:TextField ID="TextShortDescription" runat="server" FieldLabel="Short Description" Name="shortDescription" />
                        <ext:Label ID="descriptionLabel" Text="Description" runat="server"></ext:Label>
                        <ext:HtmlEditor ID="TextDescription" Name="descriptionContent" runat="server">
                        </ext:HtmlEditor>
                        <ext:Checkbox ID="CheckIsPublic" runat="server" FieldLabel="IsPublic" Name="isPublic" />
                        <ext:Panel runat="server" Layout="HBoxLayout" Split="true" Frame="true">
                            <Items>
                                <ext:Checkbox ID="CheckisEmbedded" runat="server" FieldLabel="Is Embedded" Name="isEmbedded">
                                   <Listeners>
                                        <Change Fn="changeText" />
                                   </Listeners> 
                                </ext:Checkbox>
                                <ext:ToolbarFill ID="ToolbarFill2" runat="server"></ext:ToolbarFill>
                                <ext:TextField ID="TextEmbeddedCode" runat="server" Name="embeddedCode" Region="West">
                                    <Listeners>
                                        <Change Fn="isFromOtherSite_Checked" />
                                    </Listeners>
                              </ext:TextField>

                            </Items>
                        </ext:Panel>
                        <ext:Panel ID="VideoPanel" runat="server" Split="true">
                            <Content>
                                    <div runat="server" id="videoDiv" class="flowplayer">
                                       <video runat="server" id="video1" ></video>
                                    </div>
                            </Content>
                       </ext:Panel>

                        <ext:FileUploadField ID="fileUploadBroadCast" runat="server" FieldLabel="Broadcast File" Name="fileName" Hidden="false" />
                        <ext:Hidden ID="newsIdHidden" runat="server" Name="broadcastingId" />
                    </Items>
                    <BottomBar>
                        <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar2" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" Icon="Tick">
                               <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="SaveButton_Click"></Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
                            </ext:Button>
                            <ext:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reset Fields" Icon="Reload">
                                <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="Reset_Click"></Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
                            </ext:Button>

                            <ext:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Delete" Icon="Decline">
                                <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="Delete_Click"></Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
                            </ext:Button>
                        </Items>
                        </ext:Toolbar>
                    </BottomBar>
                </ext:FormPanel>
```

And set src in directevent method
this code is:

```
protected void Select(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
            this.Video1.Attributes.Add("src", "Ganesh.mp4");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your sample is throwing many Exceptions. I gave up after fixing the third exception. Is there a problem with posting a simplified .aspx code sample demonstrating the whole scenario? Something that we could copy/paste into a local test project without having to correct a bunch of mistakes? Please remove all code that is not directly associated to the problem. It would appear almost every line of code you posted is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the runat="server" attribute and an .ID, you should be able to set other properties.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Video1.Attributes.Add("src", "http://example.com/");
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <video ID="Video1" runat="server"></video>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Google is a good source of answers for these types of questions. You can use the .Addtributes Collection. `this.Video1.Attributes.Add("src", "http://example.com/");`

Comment: You mean it doesn't work with DirectEvent and DirectMethods? In this case it's better to use 
X.AddScript("Ext.get('Video1').set({ src: 'http://example.com/' })");

Comment: @DauletUrazalinov It's not work.
File is not load in flow player

Comment: Well, how about updating your sample and provide us with something to test with? A simplified .aspx code sample demonstrating the as much of the scenario as possible. Just replying back with "It's not work" does not help in any way.

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill
 I am Update my Code On Top

Comment: Its Only Work in EventArgs method

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoSrc.Attributes.Add("src", "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm");
    }

    protected void ButtonClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.AddScript("flowplayer().load('http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm')");
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
    <!-- player skin -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flowplayer/skin/minimalist.css" />

   <!-- site specific styling -->
   <style>
   body { font: 12px "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; text-align: center; padding-top: 5%; }
   .flowplayer { width: 80%; }
   </style>

    <!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ (for now) -->
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- include flowplayer -->
   <script src="flowplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" SourceFormatting="True" ScriptMode="Debug" />

    <ext:Panel runat="server">
        <Content>
            <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.417">
              <video runat="server" ID="video">
                 <source ID="videoSrc" runat="server" type="video/webm" />
              </video>
           </div>
        </Content>
    </ext:Panel>

    <ext:Button runat="server" OnDirectClick="ButtonClick" Text="Change video"></ext:Button>
</body>
</html>
```